# Analyse set of Sequences of varying length with PCA?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, pca, sequence-analysis

**Task description**

I have a dataset with strings indicating the sequence of the screens a user visit when making a purchase on an app.

A string could be: "1,2,1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,3,2,5,6". Another string could be "1,4,6,3,2,3,4" and yet another could be "1,2,3,8,7". Here each number represents a screen on the app.

The sequences vary in length roughly in the interval of 5-200.

I wish to assign binary values to the sequences depending whether they made a purchase or not. I.e. 1 if they made a purchase and 0 if they did not.

I would then like to do PCA and see what features explains the most variance when e.g. a purchase is made.

I would also like to make a simple linear regression such that I can put in an unknown sequence and get a prediction whether the user will make a purchase or not.

**Question:**

How would one do PCA on sequences like this when the lengths are not the same? Is it even possible? Or is there a better way to go about this?

I hope some clever heads can help me out :-)

BR Mikkel